# QT creator python stream video using opencv

Tags: qt, pyqt, qml, qt5, pyside

I've been at it from quite some days, searched the docs online but have not been able to find any example :/.

I want to stream video on a page using opencv.Im using QtCreator and on a QtQuick application, that is with qml files.

```
        MediaPlayer {
            id: mediaplayer
            source: "videoplayback.mp4"
        }

        VideoOutput {
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: mediaplayer
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: playArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed: mediaplayer.play();
        }
```

Which shows this:
[image]

Now i can play the video.
But i rather want the source to be coming from my backend main.py file so i can work upon it.
The main.py file as of now is:
'''

```
class MainWindow(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

        #QTimer
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda: self.setTime())
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def setTime(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        formatDate = now.strftime("Time: %H:%M:%S %p of %Y/%m/%d")
        #print(formatDate)
        self.printTime.emit(formatDate)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    #Get Context
    main = MainWindow()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("backend", main)

    engine.load(os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "qml/main.qml"))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In the above code, basically this line:

```
engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("backend", main)
```

Is the one for connection with the qml files using

```
Connections{
    target: backend


    function onPrintTime(time){
        labelDate.text = time
    }

}
```

So in context i want to ouput video on my page using source as being from opencv. Basically it's a surviellance system app, so i  want to show multiple feeds, but if someone could help me with just one from webcam, as in how to stream it to the mediaplayer i'll be really really grateful.

**Note:** Im working with qml files inside the QT Creator application. There are a number of ways to do this with UI files but that doens't help me :/

Comment: I would use `QWidget` to create own widget and replace function `paint()` to display  frame - and it would use `QTimer` to repeate it again and again with next frames from `OpenCV`. I have only example for [wxPython + OpenCV](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/cv2/wxPython-CV-widget/main.py) and [tkinter + OpenCV](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/cv2/tkinter-CV%20-%20minimal%20version/main.py) and [PyGame + OpenCV](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/pygame/cv2-stream/main-1-full-window.py)

Comment: using Google I found [Displaying Opencv images in PyQT – Image Tracking](https://www.imagetracking.org.uk/2020/12/displaying-opencv-images-in-pyqt/) and it seems interesting.

Comment: @furas yupp that's working with ui files :,/ . Im working with qml files and python.

Comment: I think you will have to resign `qml`. But maybe someone will have better idea.